# How to remove Fractional part of seconds from date time column using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to change this datetime column, I want to remove the year:month:Day and.500

[image]

Comment: How did you load the data in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the desired dtype, you can either [`dt.floor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) or convert to string with [`dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
# example
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ['1970-01-01 00:25:47.500']})

# keeping datetime type
df['time1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.floor('S')

# converting to string
df['time2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Output:

```
                      time               time1                time2
0  1970-01-01 00:25:47.500 1970-01-01 00:25:47  1970-01-01 00:25:47
```

If you also want to remove the date:

```
df['time_only'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.floor('S').dt.time

# or as string
df['time_only'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Output:

```
                      time time_only
0  1970-01-01 00:25:47.500  00:25:47
```